# MATLAB not importing all functions from Python script

Tags: python, matlab, python-3.6

I'm trying to import functions from a python script.  I actually had an old python script, example.py, which looked roughly like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def A():
  return 1
```

When I import this module, py.importlib.import_module('example'), it finds function A().

I now add a new function:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def A():
  return 1
def B():
  return 2
```

When I now import example, it still only finds A, and not B.

Is there something I need to do to get MATLAB to detect the new function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I needed to reload the module:

```
mod = py.importlib.import_module('example');
py.importlib.reload(mod);
```